# Splitting the equation on two lines

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I have the following equation (as you can see I have used `split`):

```
\begin{equation}\label{testequation}
\begin{split}
d_{m}^{\phi}\left(A,f\right)=\sqrt[m]{\mid A\left(pi\right)-f\left(pi\right)\mid^{4}+\sum_{i=1;i\neq pi}^{length\left(R\right)}\mid M\left(i\right)- \\ f\left(i\right)\mid^{7}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I want this part of the equation to be on a new line:

```
-f\left(i\right)\mid^{7}
```

And, as you can see, I have used `\\`. But, it didn't work, although I have used the same method for another formula in the same `LaTex` document and it worked.

What would be the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you can not split a square root. One way of resolve the problem is to use `()^{1/m}` instead of `\sqrt[m]{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d_{m}^{\phi}\left(A,f\right) = \left( \mid A\left(pi\right) - f\left(pi\right)\mid^{4} + \sum_{i=1;i\neq pi}^{length\left(R\right)} \mid M\left(i\right)+\right. \\
\left. \vphantom{\sum_{i=1;i\neq pi}^{length\left(R\right)}} -f\left(i\right)\mid^{7}\right)^{1/m}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can not either split parenthesis in two different rows, for this reason I used `\right.` and `\left.` to close and open the parenthesis without typing them. I also used the `\vphantom` command to insert an invisible sum in the second row in order to have the parenthesis with the same high in the two row.

By the way, in your situation I will split the equation just before the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclareMathOperator*\length{length}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  d_{m}^{\phi}(A,f)
  &= \Biggl(\abs{A(ip) - f(ip)}^{4}\\
  &\hphantom{{}= \Biggl(} + \sum_{i = 1 \neq p}^{\length(R)} \abs{M(i) \underbrace{+-}_{?} f(i)}^{7}\Biggr)^{\mkern -4mu 1/m}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comments:

(1) The point of the linebreak is not good.

(2) Don't use `\mid` as delimiter for absolute values; use `\lvert` and `\rvert`.

(3) I assume `length` is an operator; if I'm wrong, use `\text{length}` instead.

(4) Only use `\left`/`\right` constructions when needed; when add some extra horizontal space.

(5) In the summand, you have `+-`; this is a pointless statement.

(6) The statement `i=1;i\neq pi` seems rather wierd to me. If I'm not mistaken, this is the same as `i = 1 \neq p`.

(7) Use `ip` instead of `pi`; the latter can easily mislead one to think that you actually mean `\pi` but have forgotten the frontslash (`\`).